# SQL design in Follower/Followed model for relational databases and Follow Back functionality

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, orm, relation

Suppose I want to keep who follows who in a simple table that has two fields ;

UserId and FollowedId and I have a simple data set like ;

| UserId | FollowedId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 100 |
| 5 | 100 |
| 6 | 100 |
| 100 | 5 |
| 100 | 2 |

I just use `SELECT*FROM Followers WHERE FollowedId = 100` when I want to list all followers of the user with ID 100.

However, I want the following information in my followers list when I query ;

Who I follow among those following me.

I don't directly want who I follow and who follows like an intersection.

I want the result look like following when I query the follower list of a user with ID 100;

| UserId | FollowedId | DoIFollowBack |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | false |
| 2 | 100 | true |
| 3 | 100 | false |
| 4 | 100 | false |
| 5 | 100 | true |
| 6 | 100 | false |

I can do it using another query but just wanted to ask the most efficient way of doing it ?

Having another column to keep this bidirectional relation ?
Make another query once I get the follower list to see which ones among them I follow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an intersect within a CTE to get the userids, and then Case Expression for your third column:

```
with follow_back as (
  select userid, followedid
  from my_data
  where followedid = 100
  intersect
  select followedid, userid
  from my_data)
select userid, followedid,
case 
  when userid in (select userid from follow_back) then 'true' else 'false' end DoIFollowBack
from my_data
where followedid = 100
```

Output:

```
| userid | followedid | DoIFollowBack|
| ------ | ---------- | ------------ |
| 1      | 100        | false |
| 2      | 100        | true  |
| 3      | 100        | false |
| 4      | 100        | false |
| 5      | 100        | true  |
| 6      | 100        | false |
```

Comment: do you also have an idea on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73888248/sql-query-for-searching-data-in-both-table-at-the-same-time ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this with a self-join using a left outer join and evaluating the success of the join condition:

```
SELECT
  f1.*, f2 is not null as DoIFollowBack
FROM
  Followers f1
  left join Followers f2 on
    f2.FollowedId = f1.UserId and
    f1.FollowedId = f2.UserId
WHERE
  f1.FollowedId = 100
```

This should scale nicely should you expand it to more (or even all) users.

Comment: It doesn't reflect DoIFollowBack correctly, all of them seem to be true altough just two of them has to be

Comment: interesting...  it did when I ran it (just double checked)!  I wonder what is amiss.  You copied the code literally?  If you switch any of those joins, which look nearly alike, it will not work as expected.