# SQL - query for searching data in both table at the same time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm, relation

Suppose I have a table called **UserFollows**, where I keep Follow relationships ;

| UserId | FollowedId |
| --- | --- |

Then I have a general **Users** table and it is like ;

| Id | Username |
| --- | --- |

I use a query like the following when I want to get all followers of a user with ID **100** ;

```
SELECT*FROM UserFollows WHERE FollowedId = 100;
```

And suppose that I also want to query the following case ;

I want to search among the followers of a particular user, with a specific Username.

So, It should be like `GET ME ALL OF THE USERS THAT HAS THE WORD 'hey' IN THEIR USERNAMES AMONG THOSE FOLLOWING ME`

If I had Username in my UserFollows table , I'd easily write it like ;

```
SELECT*FROM UserFollows WHERE FollowedId = 100 AND Username LIKE '%a';
```

But I don't keep their Usernames in UserFollows

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Users table in the query.

```
SELECT uf.*
FROM UserFollows uf
  inner join Users u on u.Id = uf.UserId
WHERE uf.FollowedId = 100 
  AND u.Username LIKE '%a';
```

or, more clearly

```
SELECT uf.*
FROM UserFollows uf
  inner join Users follower on follower.Id = uf.UserId
  inner join Users followed on followed.Id = uf.FollowedId
WHERE followed.UserName = 'ME'
  AND follower.Username LIKE '%a';
```

Although "followed" may be a keyword, so you would need different aliases or you would need to handle the names appropriately.